# How to compile P4 from source code?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am a student in Computer Science, and I am learning programming with Pascal.

---

I have found an interesting Pascal compiler, **P4** (http://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/pascal/).

To know more about Pascal, I am trying to compile their source code, but I failed.

In this web page, they said:

> 1. Compile pcom.p and pint.p with a Pascal compiler. You obviously have to have a Pascal compiler already. This gives you a Pascal compiler (pcom) that produces P4 code, and an interpreter (pint) that runs P4 code.
> 2. To use the compiler, run pcom with the Pascal program as standard input. This produces any diagnostics on standard output, and its code on a Pascal file that is called prr. Check with your Pascal compiler how this gets assigned to a file in the filestore. You may have to change the lines 'rewrite(prr)' in pcom.p and pint.p and 'reset(prd)' in pint.p for your compiler, for instance to "rewrite(prr, 'prr')" etc.
> 3. To run the resulting code, run pint with the prr output produced by pcom as input for the file 'prd', and input for the compiled Pascal program on standard input.

I have compiled it with **Free Pascal** (on https://ideone.com/), but failed too.

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4+dfsg-4 [2014/10/14] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2014 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for i386
Compiling pcom.p
pcom.p(1,3) Warning: Unsupported switch "$L"
pcom.p(88,23) Fatal: Syntax error, ":" expected but ")" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppc386 returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)
```

I don't know how to compile this source code in Windows machine, because I know **Pascal language only**.

---

Can I compile it with **Turbo Pascal** (without any requirement) on **Windows XP**? Can you remove some part of script for **Pascal compiling only**?

Comment: Seems like P4's source is not supported by Free Pascal, the same way you can't compile GCC from source using Visual Studio. Try compiling it with P4 itself - download the binary, and use that to compile the source.

Comment: Unmodified versions will not compile with Turbo Pascal since P4/P5 are "the other" dialect family, not Borland but more J&W/ISO like. In the past there were versions adapted to P4 on the web though. In general resurrecting things in TP is painful, Free Pascal is a much better bet. It supports more, is native Windows, and doesn't have painful 16-bit memory limitations

Answer (score 7):

Free Pascal's Florian has been working getting Scott Moore's [P5](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/p5.html) compiler (which is a P4 compiler accepting a larger subset of Pascal) to work with **FPC's ISO mode** for old sources. However it will work (mostly) only in development versions (including the upcoming  "stable" branch 3.0.x).

I tried last summer and it compiled and generally worked with FPC 3.x and the -Miso parameter (to select ISO style dialects).  IIRC the last thing fixed was ISO style parameter transfer.

I quickly tried the referenced P4 compiler version and it seems to stumble on a few spots with "comment this" comments related to switching back and fro from ISO Mode. If I comment those files, pint compiles. (and then you could run the original bytecode if necessary)

pcom then still stumbles on taking the ord() of a pointer, which is obviously not very portable either, but unfortunately with 20+ occurrences that have to be replaced with ord(ptrint()).

pcom still doesn't compile then, FPC doesn't like passing union fields to VAR parameters. Working around that with a variable and the source compiles, 15 minutes total.

The **fixed sourcecode** with extra mode statements is at http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/files/p4fixed.zip  but **requires (as yet unreleased) FPC 3.0 or newer.**

The resulting EXE binary can compile the original pcom source to bootstrap itself to bytecode.

Comment: Small nitpick: Pascal-p5 does not compile a "larger subset of Pascal", it compiles (all) of ISO 7185 Pascal, not a subset. Pascal-P4 was a subset compiler by definition: it was never designed to compile all of pascal, but only the minimum necessary to self compile.

Comment: If I say Pascal I mean Pascal. If I mean to say "ISO Pascal", I say "ISO Pascal" or better even "ISO-xxxx" Pascal, see http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/ansiiso.txt Fourth Q&A

Answer (score 1):

You want to get an ISO 7185 compliant compiler to compile that. It is true that Pascal-P4 (the proper name) was written prior to the ISO 7185 standard. However, the adaption to the standard is generally less of a change set than adaption to a dielect.

You will find that work already done and documented at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pascalp4/

It specifies use of GPC. However, as Marco said, it is possible with more work to adapt to FPC, and I believe the FPC folks are improving the ISO 7185 capability of their compiler.

Having said that, I'm not sure why Pascal-P4 would be an interesting target. Pascal-P4 was a subset compiler, meaning an incomplete implementation of Pascal. You will find a complete implementation as Pascal-P5:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pascalp5/

And I believe it has less portability issues as well.

Good luck.